# AdWords API with WP

Tags: php, api

Does anyone know a moron-proof way or guide to use the Google AdWords API with Wordpress?

I can write PHP to a vaguely acceptable level. Just looking to populate a table with some basic live spending stats but have no experience with API integration. Most guides seem to be in Python or in the Google apps developer.

0 Results showing in WPSE

Comment: Do you have idea for general PHP implementation of what you want first? I vaguely remember there is PHP SDK from Google.

Comment: Hi Rarst, I basically just wanted to build an admin table to compare our AdWords spend to people signing up on our site and making accounts. All I would need to grab would be a daily spend & clicks for certain Campaigns to compare the two figures. I write my own PHP and am relatively comfortable with new ideas. Just don't really know where to start with setting it all up & can't seem to find any relevant information on it.